# data in text field disapearing

Tags: ios5, uitextfield, xcode4.3

I have a view controller that pushes to another page on the same class.  All data entered into the text fields on the new page vanishes as soon as I move away form it.  Im assuming im missing a step here somewhere?

Do I have to connected something in page to to my original view controller?

Otherwise im going to have one long page at this rate.

xcode 4.3

Comment: can you share a little code? Especailly how do you push to other viewController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what you are saying.  You have a screen that calls another screen.  You call the new screen and enter data on that new screen and then navigate back to the original screen.  Then you call the second screen again and the data is now missing.

Each time you call a screen you create a new UIViewController (or a subclass of that class) object.  It only knows what you tell it when you create it and afterward.  When you navigate back to the original screen the new screen's view controller is destroyed and all data in it unless you store the data back in the "model" (MVC) or original screen.  So if you need to have the new screen show the data that was entered into it a previous time you will need to store that information in the "model" of your application or the screen that calls it. Then when you call the new screen "push" the stored data back into it.

If you are unfamiliar with the "Model" in Apple's Model-View-Controller pattern here is a good reference.  [Apple MVC](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH6-SW1)

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes thats exactly whats happening, thanks for explaining that. I had a quick read of the Apple documentation you linked to and as usual feel more confused than when I started. In simple terms how do I store the information the model or original page? My end goal is to have perhaps two to three hundred pages whereas user can enter test results, each page having approx. 4 - 8 text fields.  I have a think im going about this wrong as my current design is one long page and im linking up about 800 text fields and then writing another 800 lines of code to attach the results to an email body string

Comment: Are you familiar with Object Oriented Programming?  If so, you can store the data in the original view controller by passing a reference to it into the new view controller.  Then you can set values.  The model is a little more involved.  It requires a "way" to store your data such as Apple's Core Data framework.  If you are not very familiar with Object Orient Programming, this may be a good time to step back and get some good books on it and learn how to interact objects in a program.

Comment: If you want to hold a lot of data which is what it sounds like in your comment.  Look into Core Data.  It is an Apple framework that is design to hold, store, and query data.  It is very powerful.

Comment: Thanks Rob, I'm new to programing in general, I find the books quite hard to follow and have found stack overflow and YouTube invaluable resource.  I shall look Into core data as I need to learn this.  Thank you for taking the time to explain this.  Regards James